# Cannot find module './service-account.json' or its corresponding type declarations while deploying firebase with netlify functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, aws-lambda

I am deploy a serveless function on netlify that has a firebase realtime database setup in it. The code works in development mode when I call `netlify dev --live` but when I am trying to deploy my repo it is failing to build it. I am getting an issue while importing my firebase service-account file. `error TS2307: Cannot find module './service-account.json' or its corresponding type declarations.`

I am importing my file as such `import serviceAccount from "./service-account.json"` from the same folder in order to avoid adding a path given because all other files are successfully imported. How can I fix this issue?